# PHP include file with a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit, web-development-server

Just started working with the PHPUnit framework and I'm trying to incorporate it into existing code.

Let's say I a class `Math` and I have it written like below,

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * Date: 19/12/2017
 * Time: 16:22
 */

include_once 'include/testing_namespace.php';

class Math extends TestCase {

    function isEven($x) {
        if ($this->assertInternalType(IsType::TYPE_NUMERIC)) {
            if ($x % 2 == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function isOdd($y) {
        if ($this->assertInternalType(IsType::TYPE_NUMERIC)) {
            if ($y % 2 >= 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And I have a php file `include/testing_namespace.php` like so,

```
<?php

namespace testing;

use PHPUnit\Util\PHP;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\IsType;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;

$path = $_SERVER['APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH'];

// class includes, may need to branch these off into separate include files
include_once $path . '\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Assert\Functions.php';
include_once $path . '\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php';
include_once $path . 'vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\IsEqual.php';
include_once $path . 'vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\IsFalse.php';
include_once $path . 'vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\IsEmpty.php';
include_once $path . 'vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\Constraint\IsNull.php';

?>
```

Let's say I'm testing like so,

```
$m = new testing\Math();

$integer1 = 8;

var_dump($m->isEven($integer1));
die();
```

(this seemed to work fine for a while)

But let's say the file I'm testing in has a function declared also called `isEven` that is not in a namespace but is also included in the file.

Let's say `oldfuncs/OldMath.php` also has an `isEven()` function with the same name.

First question is, am I using namespaces correctly here? Also am I allowed to include a file with a namespace declaration and will that put the file that's including it into that namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Realized I was trying to use two namespaces in the same file essentially by trying to `use PHPUnit\Framework\` and having a namespace that includes the functions for PHPUnit directly.